# Clarification on subset sum

Tags: subset-sum

This is programming project for a class of mine, I'm not looking for an answer but more of an explanation of the problem. I don't really understand what is being asked.. [image]

Here is another input/ output:
input:
1 2 3 3 4 5
output:
1 2 3 3

I don't understand how we are getting this output, can someone explain it to me simpler? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is `1 2 3 3 4 5`, the subsequences are:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 3
1 2 3 3 4
1 2 3 3 4 5
2
2 3
2 3 3
...
```

Over all the subsequences, `1 2 3 3` is such that `|(1 + 2 + 3 + 3) - (4 + 5)| = 0` is minimal.

If we take the subsequence `2 3 3`, we have `|(2 + 3 + 3) - (1 + 4 + 5)| = |8 - 10| = 2` which is greater.

However, I'm also confused by the meaning of "subsequence". I thought that, the subsequences of `1 2 3 4 5` should be:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2
2 3
2 3 4
2 3 4 5
3
3 4
3 4 5
4
4 5
5
```

But according to the subject, the optimal subsequence is `1 2 4` which is not in my list. It's in fact a subset of the set `S`. So be careful, there are many combinations.